# How to run the class method set with client keyword to run in batch?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

The *`run`* method shown below is from the class *`Tutorial_RunbaseBatch`* to run it in batch.

I made the following changes:

1. Modified the method *constructSecurityKeySet*  in class *SysSecurity* to `server client static public SecurityKeySet constructSecurityKeySet()`
2. Modified the method *runJobStatic*  in class *BatchRun* to `server client static void runJobStatic(recId batchId)`

I am aware of the fact that I should not be playing around with the framework classes but this is just a research. It worked fine until I added the following code sections.

#### Code change 1:

```
MenuItemName    menuItemName;
AccessType      act;
```

#### Code change 2:

```
act = securitySet.secureNodeAccessmenuItemName,SysSecurity::accessRecType2UtilElementType(AccessRecordType::MenuItemDisplay)); // Line 24
```

Now, I get the below error message after adding the above code sections

```
The server-side impersonated (RunAs) session tried to invoke a method that is available for client-side processing only.
(S)\Classes\Tutorial_RunbaseBatch\run - line 24 
(S)\Classes\BatchRun\runJobStatic - line 62 //which is  batchClass.run();
```

The *SecurityKeySet(SystemClass)* has the property *RunOn* set to **`calledFrom`** and is executed wherever the object is called from, which could be *client* or *server*. It also has dependencies on Class *Batchable* and *BatchRunable*. Both the classes have the property `RunOn` set to **`calledFrom`**

I tried changing the properties to server on the classes  but that did not work

Is there anyway to make this code work?

#### Complete code:

```
public void run()
{
    SecurityKeySet      securitySet;
    UserGroupId         fromUserGroupId;
    DomainId            domainId;
    MenuItemName        menuItemName;
    AccessType          act;
    ;

    #OCCRetryCount

    fromUserGroupId = "XXXX";
    domainId        = "YYYY";

    if (!this.validate())
        throw error("");

    try
    {
        ttsbegin;
        // this.Update();
        securitySet=SysSecurity::constructSecurityKeySet();//error
        securitySet.loadGroupRights(fromUserGroupId,domainId);
        act = securitySet.secureNodeAccess(menuItemName,SysSecurity::accessRecType2UtilElementType(AccessRecordType::MenuItemDisplay));
        ttscommit;
    }
    catch (Exception::Deadlock)
    {
        retry;
    }
    catch (Exception::UpdateConflict)
    {
        if (appl.ttsLevel() == 0)
        {
            if (xSession::currentRetryCount() >= #RetryNum)
            {
                throw Exception::UpdateConflictNotRecovered;
            }
            else
            {
                retry;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw Exception::UpdateConflict;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Reason for the issue:

`SysSecurity` class is by default set to run on the *`Client`*. Changing the method *constructSecurityKeySet* to **`server client static`** will *not* help to run the code on the server. You can change the *RunOn* property on the class SysSecurity but there might be a reason why it is set to run on `Client`. Hence, I would not recommend the option of changing the *RunOn* mode to `Client`.

However, if you still want to try running the code in batch. You can read through the below description about the same error that I faced and how I resolved the issue using a workaround.

#### Similar issue:

I faced the same error message while trying to run *`SalesInvoice`* report in Batch to e-mail invoice PDFs.

`The server-side impersonated (RunAs) session tried to invoke a method that is available for client-side processing only.`

The issue with my scenario was the report had an image and embedding logo into the report involved client side processing and the batch process could not handle that while running on the server. Jobs added to the batch process always runs on the `Server`.

Perform the following steps in AX to find this information.

1. Navigate to `Basic \ Inquiries \ Batch job`
2. Click the batch job
3. Click `View tasks` on the right side to bring the tasks window
4. On the Tasks window, the column *`Run location`* should display **`Server`**, where the job executes.

#### Caution:

I would suggest using caution with the below mentioned approach to update the batch job data in the database using T-SQL query.

#### Possible fix:

To run the *`SalesInvoice`* job on the client, like it used to do in 4.0, I ended up modifying the value directly in the database using the below query.

```
UPDATE dbo.BATCH SET RUNTYPE = 0 WHERE CAPTION = '<Your job caption name...>'
```

Once the query has been executed to update the batch job data, verify that the *`Run location`* column under the Tasks window of the job is set to **`Client`**. When the job task is set to run in *Client*, it will not execute unless the Batch processing is initiated. Batch processing can be started by navigating to `Basic \ Periodic \ Batch \ Processing`.

Comment: nice description...much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a batch job to execute on the client tier, override the `runsImpersonated` method (inherited from `RunBaseBatch` class) and make it return false:

```
public boolean runsImpersonated()
{
    return false; // always on the client
}
```

Regards.